# Find old CNAME for domain registered on google

Tags: domains, cname

I have mistakenly replace the CNAME with a new one, without writing the old one down.

Is there a way to find the old CNAME?

I checked on `https://dnschecker.org/` but the domain is already resolved to the new name.

Comment: The company hosting your nameservers and hence publishing your CNAME records may have some kind of history and help you on that, but you are not really giving a lot of details. If your record existed only for a short time and was not used, basically no monitoring tools will have seen it, and hence only your DNS provider can help, or noone.

Comment: Why is it important where the domain was registered?